# Error : FacebookSDK has not been initialized yet using react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

So I am trying to add  a facebook sign up connect to firebase to my react-native application and  expo keep telling me this error . I dont really know what to do because I thought that Facebook SDK was auto initialized on Application start.

This is my Sign In function.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the documentation: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/facebook/, you need to initialize the SDK with this function:

```
Facebook.initializeAsync(appId: string | undefined, appName: string | undefined): Promise<void>
```

> Calling this method ensures that the SDK is initialized. You have to call this method before calling logInWithReadPermissionsAsync to ensure that Facebook support is initialized properly.

You should call this method in your App.js or any top level component.

Comment: @PhilippeVincent do not forget to mark this question as resolved

Comment: Am haivng the same problem but when i add the line in the anwser i get syntax erorrs where exactly am i supposed to add that line?

Answer (score 2):

Came here from Github, after upgrading from Expo SDK 35 => 36 ran into this issue.

Adding this line to app.json fixed it:

```
"facebookAutoInitEnabled": true
```

From docs: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/facebook/

The above answer may work as well, but this fixed it in my case